# Invoke methods from aws-apigateway-api-sdk android

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, aws-api-gateway

I have aws apigateway generated android sdk. I have included generated jar file and included this in build_gradle file.

Following is the sdk code.
Can anyone please tell me how can I invoke methods in android app? I have user token from user pool after successful login. I need to use this token to sign request to the API.

```
@Service(
    endpoint = "https://xxxxx.execute-api.zzzz.amazonaws.com/yyyy"
)
public interface StagingTestClient {
ApiResponse execute(ApiRequest var1);

@Operation(
    path = "/accounts",
    method = "GET"
)
void accountsGet();

@Operation(
    path = "/accounts",
    method = "POST"
)
void accountsPost();

@Operation(
    path = "/accounts",
    method = "DELETE"
)
void accountsDelete();

@Operation(
    path = "/accounts",
    method = "OPTIONS"
)
void accountsOptions();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is covered in the API Gateway documentation:

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/how-to-generate-sdk-android.html

Note: in order to have a meaningful SDK in Android you will need to create Request/Response models.